# How to run application on virtual machine in python script. unknown file suffix

Tags: python, vmrun

How to run application on virtual machine in python script

```
 db_tool = os.path.join(r'C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware VIX\vmrun.exe')
 db_name=r"-T esx -h https://10.10.10.10/sdk -u user -p password -gu user -gp password runProgramInGuest '[datastore1] datastore1/datastore1.vmx' -interactive notepad.exe"
 p = subprocess.Popen([db_tool, '-T' ,'server', '-h', 'https://10.10.10.10/sdk', '-u', 'user', '-p', 'password', '-gu', 'user', '-gp', 'password', 'runProgramInGuest', '"[datastore1]"', 'datastore1/datastore1.vmx','-interactive' ,'notepad.exe']
 p.communicate()
```

I receive following error: Unable to connect to host. Error: Cannot open VM: "[datastore1]", unknown file suffix

Comment: If you run the command in a console manually you'll get the same result. This is not a Python issue. Also, what is `result_dir` o0

Comment: As mentioned, this is not a programming problem, this is a tool/server issue and can be solved by following these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342552/vmware-vix-vmrun-command-error-unable-to-connect-to-host-version-not-found or asking the question on ServerFault.

Comment: Another error within start application

Comment: Another error? what error?...

Comment: "Unable to connect to host. Error: Cannot open VM: "[datastore1]", unknown file suffix" 
i don't know how to pass quotes in subprocess.Popen ([....,'"[datastore1]"', 'datastore1/datastore1.vmx', ...])

Comment: You pass quotes by doing `"This is my string: \"wham bam\" and there's many like it"` :)